# folder structure for struts2 application to deploy in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

i am trying to deploy a struts2 based application to google app engine. i am using maven to build and deploy the application. i performed the following steps to create the application structure:

1) execute the command **mvn archetype:generate** to create the core application structure. i followed the interactive command line steps and the structure got generated.

2) added dependencies such as given in this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-struts-2-example/) in the pom.xml of the war directory.

3) copied java classes and actions in the src folder.

4) created struts.xml in **src** folder of war directory and added action declarations.

5) i executed **mvn clean install**. it got successfully executed.

6) i deployed the application locally using **mvn appengine:devserver** in the ear directory.

now i try to navigate to an action. i get the error: **"no action mapped"**. i am guessing that its not able use struts.xml properly. if that's the problem, where should i put struts.xml ? if not, what can be the reason for this error?

my pom.xml for war directory is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.me.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>teststrutsapplication-war</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.me.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>teststrutsapplication</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1-war</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
        </dependency>







    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory> 

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

struts.xml should be under src/main/resources folder.

Also, if it helps, your index page should have extension .html and NOT .jsp. Be sure to update the  tag in your web.xml too.